# Xcode 5 slice image from images.xcassets, correctly stretched in xib, but not at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, image, storyboard

I've got this issue. In my app I use different "universal" graphical assets.
Those assets are used as background image mostly and need to be stretched or tiled.
After the process of slicing in the Images.xcassets I can see them drawing correctly in xib and storyboard, but when I launch the app in the simulator, corner edges are deformed.
Here some screens:
From Storyboard it preserves the slicing selection:
[image]
Settings in the Images.xcassets:
[image]
Running app result:
[image]

Has someone seen this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue, slicing images using the Xcode interface works only if the deploy is >=7. If you deploy on lower it just disable that functionality, displaying also a warning while building.